# Azure SQL Primary replica read/write connection redirection

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Asp.Net Core Web App running with Azure SQL.  The SQL server has a replica target in a different region.

This particular server is a Hangfire "task" server. It should participate in task execution along with the rest of the servers in the (logical) Hangfire cluster during normal operation (it should point toward *MyPrimaryLiveSql.database.com*).

In the event of a service outage in the primary region, the sql replica at *BCDRSql.database.com* goes from Read Only to Read/Write.  I would now like the Task Server to automatically start using bcdrsql.database.com as its connection string for all connections going forward.

Is there a way in either Azure SQL or Asp.Net or Azure Web App Configuration or Entity Framework Core to dynamically choose/redirect the SQL server connection string depending on if the Database is in read only or read/write mode?

I can get the database read/write status via `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability');`, but I'm not sure how to get my Data Context to use the BCDR connection string based on the result, as my DB Context is only initialized once during the startup sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely just us a failover group to solve this problem.  Please read through this link: [auto failover groups](https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-sql-server-auto-failover-groups/).  Note that this works for the automatic DR path - there is also the other active geo-replication solution and you may need control over the failover yourself (Microsoft does it in the "auto" case).  So please be aware of the level of control you need in each solution.  (Of course, if you are choosing to failover you can likely get your app to do what you want then too since you are making a change yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like Failover groups take at least 1 hour to trigger.   Is that correct?

Comment: Failover for that is controlled by Microsoft - it is a DR solution, not an HA solution across regions.  If you want an HA solution, that's already built in with just the single database.  Some regions also support zone-redundant storage and you have the replicas spread across zones (which protect against more failure modes within a single region).

Comment: Failover can get triggered earlier than 1 hour if the replica was up-to-date when the primary region went down. Otherwise it waits for the grace period before initiating a failover. Grace period can be configured from 1 to 24 hours, but not any shorter unfortunately (even if your app is ok with the data loss).